# How to fold a the sum of a column in slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a column:

```
val a: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("a")
```

which I want to sum:

```
val b: Rep[Option[Long]] = a.sum
```

If there are no rows or the sum is negative then return `0` otherwise return the sum:

```
val y: Rep[Long] = b.fold(0) { x => if (x < 0) 0 else x }
```

However this last `fold` will not compile because `x` is a `Rep[Long]` and not a `Long`.

There is an implicit conversion of `b` to `AnyOptionExtensionMethods[Rep[Option[Long]], Rep[Long]]`. It is the second type parameter `Rep[Long]` which is causing problems. I want it to be `Long`. Making that explicit looks like:

```
val c: LongJdbcType = longColumnType
val d: Shape[FlatShapeLevel, Rep[Long], Long, Rep[Long]] = Shape.repColumnShape[Long, FlatShapeLevel](c)
val e: OptionLift[Rep[Long], Rep[Option[Long]]] = OptionLift.repOptionLift[Rep[Long], Long](d)
val f: AnyOptionExtensionMethods[Rep[Option[Long]], Rep[Long]] = anyOptionExtensionMethods[Long, Rep[Long]](b)(e)
```

What I need is:

```
val d2: Shape[FlatShapeLevel, Long, Long, Long] = ???
val e2: OptionLift[Long, Rep[Option[Long]]] = OptionLift.anyOptionLift[Long, Long](d2)
val f2: AnyOptionExtensionMethods[Rep[Option[Long]], Long] = anyOptionExtensionMethods[Long, Long](b)(e2)
```

What is `d2` supposed to be? `Shape.primitiveShape` is sort of what I would expect but there would need to be an `OptionLift.constOptionLift` function. So now I'm stuck with:

```
val d3: Shape[FlatShapeLevel, Long, Long, ConstColumn[Long]] = Shape.primitiveShape[Long, FlatShapeLevel]
val e3: OptionLift[Long, Rep[Option[Long]]] = ???
val f3: AnyOptionExtensionMethods[Rep[Option[Long]], Long] = anyOptionExtensionMethods[Long, Long](b)(e3)
```

Before I go any further down the rabbit hole, how is this supposed to work?

I'm pretty sure that my intended use of `fold` is valid. At least that is what matches my intuition and also the documentation:

```
/** Extension methods for Options of single- and multi-column values */
final class AnyOptionExtensionMethods[O <: Rep[_], P](val r: O) extends AnyVal {
  /** Apply `f` to the value inside this Option, if it is non-empty, otherwise return `ifEmpty`. */
  def fold[B, BP](ifEmpty: B)(f: P => B)(implicit shape: Shape[FlatShapeLevel, B, _, BP]): BP = {
  ...
```

---

Update:

There may be a clue in `getOrElse` as it has some casting shenanigans going on:

```
  def getOrElse[M, P2 <: P](default: M)(implicit shape: Shape[FlatShapeLevel, M, _, P2], ol: OptionLift[P2, O]): P =
    // P2 != P can only happen if M contains plain values, which pack to ConstColumn instead of Rep.
    // Both have the same packedShape (RepShape), so we can safely cast here:
    fold[P, P](shape.pack(default): P)(identity)(shape.packedShape.asInstanceOf[Shape[FlatShapeLevel, P, _, P]])
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear what SQL you want to produce from the fold. The body of the fold needs to be something Slick can turn into SQL.

To handle the optional result from the database, what you could do is filter away unwanted values:

```
val query: Rep[Int] = table.map(_.number).sum
   .filter(_ >= 0)
   .getOrElse(0)
```

Which will turn into a SQL Case expression.

Or perhaps it would be clearer to run this client-side:

```
val action: DBIO[Int] =
  table.map(_.number).sum.result.map { optional =>
      // Now in Scala, client side
      optional.fold(0)(x => if (x < 0) 0 else x)
  }
```

Comment: I often forget to think about it from the SQL side. Calling it `fold` threw me off. I don't think it is quite a fold. I actually don't want it to be done in SQL, I just need this for building the result in `<>`. I was trying to avoid making those functions more complicated. I suppose I may have also been able to use a projection.